# Parse Error: no element found - parsing xlsm

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using panda to parse certain fields in 250,000 plus `xlsm` files. After running through 1000s of files, the code broke with an error message `"ParseError No element found"`.

There is no helpful information in the error and it doesn't give a filename.

```
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
        wb = pd.ExcelFile(filename)   
        try:
            data = parse_xlsms(wb, filename)
            if data[1] == True:
                data[0].to_csv(outfile, mode='a', header=False) 
            else:
                logger.info("No relevant data found in file: " + filename)
        except (Exception,ValueError, TypeError, NameError, KeyError, 
        AttributeError, IndexError) as e:
            logger.error("Exception: " +  str(e) +  " in " + filename)
        pass
```

I am not sure what would cause this error. I would expect (and prefer) to skip any files with errors and continue.

Edit:  It was a corrupt file.   I can add the filename to the loop for debugging purposes but I just want it to continue rather than breaking.  Thanks for the suggestions!  This is my first python script.

Comment: So insert a `print(filename)` at the start of each loop and narrow down which filename it was. Then check you can repro the ParseError just reading that one file. Then narrow down which line of that file by binary-searching with the `nrows` parameter. Then update your question and post the offending line(s)